# WSO2 EMM java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException

Tags: java, wso2, wso2-iot

I'm new with WSO2 products. I try WSO2 EMM and when I try to start emm 1.1.0 I get the following errors. I tried on Ubuntu, Debian and Windows and always the same issue.

It doesn't happen with the 1.0.0

```
   java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:57)
at    sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
 at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:622)
at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.loadClass(Bootstrap.java:63)
at org.wso2.carbon.bootstrap.Bootstrap.main(Bootstrap.java:45)
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: org.eclipse.core.runtime.adaptor.EclipseStarter
at org.wso2.carbon.server.CarbonLauncher.launch(CarbonLauncher.java:117)
at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.launchCarbon(Main.java:163)
at org.wso2.carbon.server.Main.main(Main.java:95)
... 6 more
```

I already saw these errors but there was no answers.
Any ideas ?
Antoine

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I answer to my own question, may be it could help...

It's still not working on linux, but it's now working on windows.

The only thing I did is ti strickly respect the folder name and structure

Let my explain:

When it was not working the structure of the folder was:

c:\wsoemm\bin...

now it's

c:\wso2\wsoeme-1.1.0\bin

This is the only thing I did to make it working

I would prefer running WSO2 EMM on linux so any help would be great.

Antoine

Answer (score 0):

After 3 days it's now working on linux

you have to change the file null.ini wich is located at

/wherever you put the folder/wso2/wso2emm-1.1.0/repository/components/default

the default file is:

```
-install
/home/nira/git/EMM/product-emm/modules/p2-profile-gen/target/wso2carbon-core-4.2.0/repository/components/default
```

change it to:

```
-install
/wherever you put the folder/wso2/wso2emm-1.1.0/repository/components/default
```

That's it